# same row multiple times in a form in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

have a form by which user can enter details about some expenses but i want to have same row in the form again and again but couldn't find out how to do that :

[image]

if you see figure above this forms works well for 1 row of data , saves well but with more then 1 row it cant . Can someone suggest any way to do that . Below are the codes :

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Expenditure(models.Model):
    exp_date = models.DateField("Expenditure_Date")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=15,default="USD")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('exp_date', 'description',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from moni.models import Expenditure
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget


class ExpenditureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #exp_date = forms.DateField(help_text="Date")
    exp_date = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    amount = forms.FloatField(initial=0)
    currency = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="USD")

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Expenditure
        fields = ('exp_date', 'amount', 'description')
```

views.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from moni.models import Expenditure
from moni.forms import ExpenditureForm

def add_expenditure(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExpenditureForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:

            print form.errors
    else:

        form = ExpenditureForm()


    return render_to_response('moni/add_expenditure.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

add_expenditure.html

```
{% extends 'moni/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Add Shipment {% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
        <h1>Add a Expenditure</h1>
        <p id="p_hide"> I am a paragraph to be hidden</p>
        <button id ="btn1">Hide Paragraph</button>

        <form id="expenditure_form" method="post" class="vDateField" action="/moni/add_expenditure/">

            {% csrf_token %}

            <table border=1>
                <tr><th><label >Date:</label></th> <th><label for="id_description">Description:</label></th><th><label for="id_amount">Amount:</label></th></tr>
            <tr><td><input class="vDateField"  name="exp_date" size="10" type="text" /></td><td>{{form.description}}</td><td>{{form.amount}}<input id="id_currency" name="currency" type="hidden" value="MYR" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input class="vDateField"  name="exp_date" size="10" type="text" /></td><td>{{form.description}}</td><td>{{form.amount}}<input id="id_currency" name="currency" type="hidden" value="MYR" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Expenditure" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that use Formeset function, Here is the idea for print form in multiple times

```
 ExpenditureFormSet = formset_factory(ExpenditureForm, extra=3,)
```

And views like

```
if formset.is_valid():
            for data in formset.cleaned_data:
```

And pass it into `{formset}` So html will print the extra 3 forms

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ModelFormSets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) instead of ModelForm.
And if you're going to add forms dynamically, use corresponding JavaScript plugin (since management form should be changed every time new form is added).