# How to print a Django Forms many times with different id

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have created this form, which is a multiple input option, populated by a queryset:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field = ModelChoiceField(queryset=TestTable.objects.all().order_by('desc1'))
    class Meta(object):
        model = BlockValue
        fields = ()
```

Whithin the same html form, I want to print the TestForm many times.

In the views.py is it possible to create an array of TestForm and print in the template using a for loop?

Comment: Yes it is, why not try it?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#configuring-html-label-tags     search for auto_id, this will give you idea

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [same row multiple times in a form in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906234/same-row-multiple-times-in-a-form-in-django)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a formset and pass it to your template:

```
 TestFormSet = formset_factory(TestForm, extra=3,)
```

then in your view:

```
def test_form_view(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'GET':

        formset = TestFormSet()


    return render_to_response('yourapp/test_form_template.html', {'formset': formset}, context)
```

and in your template:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{form.as_table}}
{% endfor %}
```

take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#dealing-with-ordering-and-deletion-of-forms) for more information